# how to convert pdf file to text file where the content is arabic

Tags: python, pdf, utf-8, encode, arabic

i have a python script that  list all the **pdf files**  in a specified directory and convert it to **text files**.

the system work perfect the problem is when i have **ARABIC** text  the script crash because its unable to search in the PDF file.

**i know that pdf are binary  but do not know how to read  ARABIC and convert it to text** 
how to fix this error ?

i tried to encode to UTF-8 and decode it but still not working

**if i try the code with comment lines at the bottom of the code the result will be converted empty text file.**

**if i try to Uncomment the lines in order to encode and decode the result will be empty converted text file with this error:**

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\test\Downloads\pdf-txt\text maker.py", line 63, in 
>       content.decode('ascii', 'ignore') UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa9' in position 50: ordinal not in
>   range(128)

## code:

```
import os
from os import chdir, getcwd, listdir, path
import codecs
import pyPdf
from time import strftime


def check_path(prompt):
    ''' (str) -> str
    Verifies if the provided absolute path does exist.
    '''
    abs_path = raw_input(prompt)
    while path.exists(abs_path) != True:
        print "\nThe specified path does not exist.\n"
        abs_path = raw_input(prompt)
    return abs_path    

print "\n"

folder = check_path("Provide absolute path for the folder: ")

list=[]
directory=folder
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(directory):
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith('.pdf'):
            t=os.path.join(directory,filename)
            ##print(t)
            ##list.extend(t)
            list.append(t)
           ## print(list)


m=len(list)
print (m)
i=0
while i<=m-1:

    path=list[i]
    print(path)
    head,tail=os.path.split(path)
    var="\\"

    tail=tail.replace(".pdf",".txt")
    name=head+var+tail




    content = ""
    # Load PDF into pyPDF
    pdf = pyPdf.PdfFileReader(file(path, "rb"))
    ##pdf = pyPdf.PdfFileReader(codecs.open(path, "rb", encoding='UTF-8'))
    # Iterate pages
    for j in range(0, pdf.getNumPages()):
        # Extract text from page and add to content
        content += pdf.getPage(j).extractText() + "\n"
    print strftime("%H:%M:%S"), " pdf  -> txt "
    f=open(name,'w')
## all this red line are added by me ##
    ##f.decode(content.encode('UTF-8'))
    ##content.encode('utf-8')
    ##content.decode('ascii', 'ignore')
    ##content.decode('unicode-escape')
    ##f.write(content)
    f.write(content.encode('UTF-8'))
    f.close
    i=i+1
```

Comment: Please show the error message and the full stacktrace in your question.

Comment: @lenz i will edit my question and add the error

Comment: @lenz i added the error can you help me to fix it ?

Comment: The line that causes the error is commented out, so apparently you got that error with a different version of the code. Please provide a version of the script that matches the error message. Also, please try to reduce your code – remove stuff that is irrelevant to the problem, until you have an example version that still produces the error, but is much shorter.

Comment: As a general suggestion, you should read up about encoding (eg. [in the official Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#encodings-and-unicode)), since it looks you are trying the `encode()` and `decode()` methods at random. Also, consider switching to Python 3. Encoding problems are far more obscure in Python 2.

Answer (score 2):

5 years later: `pypdf` has gone through major updates. Extracting Arabic text should work fine the standard way:

```py
from pypdf import PdfReader

reader = PdfReader("arabic.pdf")
full_text = ""
for page in reader.pages:
    full_text += page.extract_text() + "\n"
print(full_text)
```

If some PDF is causing issues, please [report a bug](https://github.com/py-pdf/pypdf/issues/new/choose). You need to share the `pypdf` version and the file that causes the issue.

### What NOT to do

- Don't do anything with `encode` / `decode`. It's not necessary.
- Don't use PyPDF2 / PyPDF3 / PyPDF4: The community moved to `pypdf`.

Comment: Actually, it is also advisable to post-process the text, there is a probability Arabic text can't be used directly, but needs to be converted to an appropriate sequence of Unicode characters.

Life is much easier if PDF uses a font with a well-formed cmap file, and the PDF is tagged, and the tags have ActualText attributes that can be accessed, rather than relying on the glyph layer of the PDF.

Comment: An example, reading a recently created PDF in Arabic, extracting the first word gives me the code points: U+0627 U+FEDF U+FEE4 U+FEEE U+0627 U+0631 U+062F

After running it through data cleaning: U+0627 U+0644 U+0645 U+0648 U+0627 U+0631 U+062F

Comment: Hey! You seem to be more experienced with Arabic text than I am. What do you think about giving an answer with a little bit more details on how to do the cleanup - then I would link to your answer :-)

Comment: If it's possible to achieve in a reasonable way, I want to include the parts that you would currently do with post-processing directly within pypdf (I'm the maintainer of pypdf and pypdf2). That is one reason why I'm curious for details :-)

Comment: The cleanup, often depends on needs of individual PDF files based on what software generated the PDF and what fonts are used. the ToUnicode mapping is useless for many languages. In the first instance I would initially ignore the glyph layer, what you would probably think of as the text layer. Test if PDF is tagged. If tagged, test if tags have ActualText attribute, that's where the real text is stored. If that is a bust fall back to the glyph layer using the toUnicode mapping. After first base check if Arabic presentation forms are present, convert to standard Arabic codepoints if present.

Comment: Need to try to determine if text has been visually ordered, if so you need something like  reverse bidi algorithm to get it back to logical.